# MySQL: count data with a range

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

I'm using below query to count the daily result, but now I'm make it short just show data result in `2012-06-01`.

```
SELECT DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date,A.Line,
       TRIM(A.Model) AS Model, A.Lot_no, COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Qty,
       B.name
FROM inspection_report AS A
LEFT JOIN Employee AS B
ON A.NIK=B.NIK
WHERE A.Inspection_datetime LIKE '2012-06-01%'
GROUP BY DATE(A.Inspection_datetime), TRIM(A.Model), B.name,A.Line,A.Lot_no
```

I got result like :

```
Date        Line       Model        Lot_no  Qty name
2012-06-01  FA 24   DDX6051BTQD     014A    4   Ben
2012-06-01  FA 24   DDX6051BTQD     014A    4   August
2012-06-01  FA 24   DDX630WBTXD     012A    8   August
2012-06-01  FA 17   KD-DV5506UPD    021A    20  Stue
2012-06-01  FA 17   KD-DV5606UD     114A    25  Carl
2012-06-01  FA 17   KD-DV5606UD     114A    3   Teo
```

How to do if I want to count data until target  data ex. count from `DDX6051BTQD` until `KD-DV5506UPD`. So, I'm just get the result LIKE :

```
Date          Qty
2012-06-01    36
```

Try:

```
SELECT X.DATE, SUM(X.Qty) FROM (//insert query above//)
WHERE ??????? //how to do ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below;

```
SET @userValueFrom := 'DDX6051BTQD';
SET @userValueTo :='KD-DV5506UPD';

SELECT * FROM (//insert your query above//) 
where Model >= @userValueFrom and Model <= @userValueTo ;
```

Comment: The SELECT could use your select. Just add in the where clause `SELECT X.DATE, SUM(X.Qty) FROM (//insert query above//) WHERE Model >= @userValueFrom and Model <= @userValueTo ;`